# Heroku not processing multipart form POST from Android

Tags: android, heroku

I have an API on rails 4 that accepts HTTP requests in the form of a file upload. Everything works fine on Localhost but on Heroku the POST request doesn't seem to do anything.

This is what my Android POST request looks like:

```
public static byte[] postData(String operation, byte[] binaryData) {
String urlString = baseUrl + "/" + operation;
    String boundary = "uahbkjqtjgecuaoehuaebkjahj";

    byte[] postData = null;
    URLConnection urlConnection;
    DataInputStream responseDataInputStream;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    StringBuffer startBuffer = new StringBuffer("--").append(boundary).append("\r\n");
    startBuffer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; ").append("filename=\"data.dat\"\r\n");
    startBuffer.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");
    StringBuffer endBuffer = new StringBuffer("\r\n--").append(boundary).append("--\r\n");

    String startRequestData = startBuffer.toString();
    String endRequestData = endBuffer.toString();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000); //5 seconds
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(5000);//5 seconds

        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        urlConnection.connect();
        DataOutputStream _request = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

        // Write the start portion of the request
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(startRequestData.getBytes());
        postData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        _request.write(postData);

        // Write the Binary Packet
        _request.write(binaryData);

        // Write the end portion of the request
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(endRequestData.getBytes());
        postData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        _request.write(postData);

        _request.flush();
        _request.close();

        // Read in the response bytes
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        responseDataInputStream = new DataInputStream(is);
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[responseDataInputStream.available()];

        while (responseDataInputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer);
            buffer = new byte[responseDataInputStream.available()];
        }

        byte[] responseData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        return responseData;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new byte[0];
```

}

My rails controller

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
respond_to :raw
before_filter :read_file

def read_file
 data = params[:data].tempfile
 data_compressed = ''
 File.open(data, 'r') do |file|
   file.each do |line|
    data_compressed.concat(line)
   end
 end

 @json_data = Zlib::Inflate.inflate(data_compressed)
end

def an_action
 #processing stuff
 response = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(j_response)
 send_data @json_response.to_s
end
```

Heroku logs shows that the controller action is hit but nothing more from the logs

```
2015-05-05T22:39:29.860161+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/login" host=[my app].herokuapp.com request_id=9d9c91b1-2ce2-4db5-9b54-3dea0322e211 fwd="197.237.24.179" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=1683
2015-05-05T22:40:40.952219+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/signup" host=[my app].herokuapp.com request_id=4adac44c-66e6-4001-a568-8eb913176091 fwd="197.237.24.179" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1683
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After shifting my focus from Heroku to the Android code I figured out that there was an endless loop at this section of the code:

```
while (responseDataInputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer);
        buffer = new byte[responseDataInputStream.available()];
    }
```

When theres nothing to read the return value is 0 instead of -1. So I updated it to:

```
while (responseDataInputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer);
            buffer = new byte[responseDataInputStream.available()];
        }
```

Something strange is that on localhost the first piece of code works and it should work on production too.  The documentation states that -1 is returned if the end of stream is reached [DataInputStream.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte[])). Maybe thats a discussion for another day, for now I'm using the second piece of code.

**EDIT**

This issue has haunted me for weeks and after alot of googling and tweaking of the code I would like to point out that this approach was the WRONG route. The code worked on a WIFI connection but always failed on 3G. So i'll list the code changes that finally worked.

1. use HttpURLConnection instead of URLConnection. Reason [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)
2. Increased the size of Connect and Read timeouts from 5000 to 30000 and 120000 respectively.
3. Revert the while condition to `while (responseDataInputStream.read(buffer) != -1)`